# Debug new system call without recompiling Debian kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, debian, system-calls

As the title says, I just want to test/debug a system call without recompiling the whole kernel. I'm using a Debian 4.0.15 kernel.  I've read that you can't actually add the system call to the kernel without recompiling, but I was hoping there was some way to more quickly check for errors at least. I've never really done this before but all of my implementation files are just written in C; could I compile them with gcc and run that?  I'd expect system calls get some extra access rights and I've been told not to use floating point arithmetic at all, so I imagine there are other limitations present in system calls as well that wouldn't be caught when compiling with gcc.

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on what aspect of a system call you wish to test/debug?  Do you plan to target a specific system call in your testing/debugging effort?  The question, as it is now, is quite broad.

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer I mean, being able to test absolutely anything without recompiling would be helpful.  If there are syntax errors, seeing print statements, anything.  I'm not asking for how to test specific functionality, I'd just like to catch as many errors (syntax, logic, etc.) as possible before committing to recompiling the whole kernel.

Comment: How would you add a system call in kernel without recompiling it ? imho it's not possible ...

Answer (score 1):

The system call dispatching table is constructed from an elaborate program in the process of building the system.  The program takes care that the same system call will get always the same entry point, so you cannot get a different call than the one requested.  There's no means to register a system call at runtime and make it available to user programs (I think this is, between other things, due to security reasons)  But you can install a new call that calls an installed function through a pointer, and install by default a do-nothing function that is changed at module loading and replaced by the dumb default on module unload.  This allows you to move your code to a module and load/unload it dynamically, without having to recompile the base kernel. Then, after you have tested the code, you can eliminate the call to function through a pointer and call the function directly.